# Cannot Access Parent instance variable in child

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working on scrapy framework.

I have some common properties which i want in all of my spiders so i made a BaseSpider.

**BaseSpider**

```
import scrapy
from src.LoggerFactory import get_logger
import ConfigParser
from redis import Redis


class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    logger = get_logger()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(scrapy.Spider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
        config.read('../../config.cfg')
        self.config = config
        self.redis = Redis(host=config.get('redis', 'host'), port=config.get('redis', 'port'))

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

And my EbaySpider is as follows

**EbaySpider**

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapper.items import Product
from BaseSpider import BaseSpider


class EbaySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "ebay"
    allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.redis # Throws AttributeError: 'EbaySpider' object has no attribute 'redis'
        exit()
```

Strangest part is i can still access `scrapy.Spider` properts in my `EbaySpider` although it is not inherited from `scrapy.Spider`.

Also, if there is any scrapy way to extend Spiders please suggest as i wasn't able to find that in their documentations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `super` usage is wrong.

> a typical superclass call looks like this:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(C, self).method(arg)
```

[As per official 2.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Where's your looks like:

```
class C(B):
    def method(self, arg):
        super(B, self).method(arg)
              ^
```